# SQL CASE in WHERE Clause using parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have 4 date columns in my Date table, I want to write a query that will hit one of these columns depending on that user passes as a parameter:
here is a part of my code:

```
Select ...
FROM...
WHERE
CASE 
WHEN @timePeriod =  'Cal' THEN d.CalendarYear  = @year 
WHEN @timePeriod =  'Fin' THEN d.FinancialYear = @year 
WHEN @timePeriod =  'Mar' THEN d.YearEndedMarch = @year 
WHEN @timePeriod =  'Sep' THEN d.YearEndedSep = @year 
END
```

So the user will provide a TimePeriod, e.g. 'Fin' and the actual year 'FY2013 - 2014'.
Thus, if the user proivdes @timePeriod = 'Fin' I want the query to filter the Date table by @year.

Here is a sample of what Im trying to get:
I have some data in the Data column, and then I want the query to filter the results by one of these 4 calendar columns.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a front end language or just pure backend?

Comment: Can you provide some examples using data to show what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You do do this without a `CASE` statement and using simple logic:

```
Select ...
FROM...
WHERE
    (@timePeriod =  'Cal' AND d.CalendarYear  = @year)
OR  (@timePeriod =  'Fin' AND d.FinancialYear = @year) 
OR  (@timePeriod =  'Mar' AND d.YearEndedMarch = @year) 
OR  (@timePeriod =  'Sep' AND d.YearEndedSep = @year)
```

[Given the cardinality for all these columns is very similar (or identical) you should not have to worry about parameter sniffing caching an inappropriate query plan.]

Comment: this got rid of the syntax error, but now Im getting:Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'M2013 - 2014' to data type int. This is for the @year variable which I have declared as Varchar. Im not trying to convert it to int, but why does it keep trying to?

Comment: Looks like the CalendarYear is stored as an integer or is being implicitly converted to one. the rest are alphanumeric, so string equivalence check would work. Since the year variable is a varchar, wrap your column references in CONVERT i.e. CONVERT(varchar(max), d.CalendarYear).

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variation:

```
Select ...
FROM...
WHERE @year = 
  CASE 
     WHEN @timePeriod =  'Cal' THEN d.CalendarYear
     WHEN @timePeriod =  'Fin' THEN d.FinancialYear
     WHEN @timePeriod =  'Mar' THEN d.YearEndedMarch
     WHEN @timePeriod =  'Sep' THEN d.YearEndedSep
  END
```

And this one, which may be faster than one using `CASE` or `OR`:

```
 Select ...
 FROM...
 WHERE  @timePeriod = 'Cal' and d.CalendarYear = @year
 UNION ALL
 Select ...
 FROM ....
 WHERE  @timePeriod = 'Fin' and d.FinancialYear = @year
 UNION ALL
 ... etc...
```

The idea behind this second one is that each `SELECT` is very simple and can take advantage of any indexes you might have, while the `UNION ALL` combines them without attempting to filter out duplicates.  Since @timePeriod can only have one value at a time, no records will be returned for 3 of the queries, and there'll be no duplicates to require removing.

Comment: Im not sure how the first one is suppose to work? the @year is set by the user. The use says: I want the YearEndedMarch calender and I want the '@year' = 2013-14 year

Comment: @user2343837 The thing you have to remember about a CASE statement in SQL is that it's really a function.  It returns a value.  So I'm saying 'WHERE @year = [the result of this case statement]", which, depending on the value of `@timePeriod`, can be the value of `d.CalendarYear`, or `d.FinancialYear`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-query:

```
  Select ...
  FROM
  (
  SELECT
  CASE 
  WHEN @timePeriod =  'Cal' THEN d.CalendarYear
  WHEN @timePeriod =  'Fin' THEN d.FinancialYear
  WHEN @timePeriod =  'Mar' THEN d.YearEndedMarch
  WHEN @timePeriod =  'Sep' THEN d.YearEndedSep
  END as date
  FROM...) t
  WHERE t.date = @year
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello we can make query more faster by using Union all with in the Subquery i am just giving syntax like example because there is no availability of data

```
 Select t.TimePeriod,t.CalendarYear
  FROM
  (
  SELECT TIMEID,
   @timePeriod =  'Cal' FROM @x where  t.CalendarYear = @year
   UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMEID,
   @timePeriod =  'FIN' FROM @x where  t.CalendarYear = @year
    UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMEID,
   @timePeriod =  'MAR' FROM @x where  t.CalendarYear = @year
    UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMEID,
   @timePeriod =  'Sep' FROM @x where  t.CalendarYear = @year

) t
  WHERE t.date = @year
```